# update Query in db2

Tags: db2, insert-update

My table looks like below,

```
Table Name: Number_List
Columns Name: Num_ID INTEGER 
              First_Number VARCHAR(16) 
              Last_Number VARCHAR(16)
```

In that, Num_ID is PK. and the rest of the columns First_Number and Last_Number always have a 8 digit number.
my requirement is to update that column to 6 Digit entry..

Consider the Entries in the two columns are `32659814` (First_Number) and `32659819` (Last_Number). Now I need to write a update query to change the entries in the table to `326598` (First_Number) and `326598` (Last_Number).

and this table has 15K entries and i need to update the whole in single query in single execution.

Please help me to resolve this.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is [`SUBSTR`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000854.html):

```
UPDATE SESSION.NUMBER_LIST
   SET FIRST_NUMBER = SUBSTR(FIRST_NUMBER, 1,6)
      ,LAST_NUMBER  = SUBSTR(LAST_NUMBER,  1,6)
```

Comment: Cool Bhamby.. tHANKS FOR THE ANSWER!! So my actual query look like below,
`UPDATE NUMBER_LIST
   SET FIRST_NUMBER = SUBSTR(FIRST_NUMBER, 1,6)
      ,LAST_NUMBER  = SUBSTR(LAST_NUMBER,  1,6)
WHERE FIRST_NUMBER <> NULL AND LAST_NUMBER <>NULL;`
AND IS THERE ANY PROBLEM IF I HAVE THAT LAST_NUMBER.LENGH <=6??

Comment: ... SET FIRST_NUMBER = CASE WHEN LENGTH(FIRST_NUMBER) > 6 THEN SUBSTR(FIRST_NUMBER, 1,6) ELSE FIRST_NUMBER END ...